# Integer sent from javascript to php to mysql comes back different

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, variables, integer

Okay, im completely confused now.

I have an app in javascript which sends an array of info to a php script, which in turn saves it to a mysql database.

The info contains a unique number which is between 8 and 20 characters which is used as the mysql unique index and all that and has a number which is incremented from 1 assigned to each unique number.

When i send **1066998880** it works perfectly by checking to see if the row exists, then adding 1 to its score.

but when i send **100005075040249** it saves to the mysql database as **2147483647** and returns **Duplicate of 2147483647**.

not sure what im doing wrong. but heres my code:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$.ajax({ url: 'URL',
     data: { Unique_ID: Unique_ID, first: first, last: last, email: email},
     type: 'post',
     success: function(output) { 'functions'};
```

**PHP**

```
$Unique_ID = $_POST["Unique_ID"];
$first = $_POST["first"];
$last = $_POST["last"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$count = 1;

// Connect to server and select database.
$connection = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die(mysql_error()); 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `comfort_lavender`.`Players` WHERE Unique_ID = '$Unique_ID'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    //found
    mysql_query("UPDATE `comfort_lavender`.`Players` SET `count` = `count`+1 WHERE     Unique_ID= '$Unique_ID'");
    $score = mysql_query("SELECT count FROM `comfort_lavender`.`Players` WHERE `Unique_ID` = '$Unique_ID'");
    $got = mysql_fetch_array( $score ); 
    echo $got['count'];
}else{
    //not found
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `comfort_lavender`.`Players` (`Unique_ID`, `first`, `last`, `email`, `count`) VALUES ('$Unique_ID', '$first', '$last', '$email', '1');") or die(mysql_error());
    echo 1;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2,147,483,647 is the largest value an INT (4 byte integer) can store in MySQL.

Change data type to BIGINT (8 byte integer) (those can store values up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807).

Answer (score 2):

The simpliest answer is that your column's data type is `SIGNED INT` and the maximum value is `2147483647`.

You are inserting a value that is greater than the range that is why the value is truncated into its maximum allowed value. There are two possible data type on this,

one is `VARCHAR(18)` which changes your data type into string.

and the other one is `BIGINT` which can holds up to:

for SIGNED BIGINT `-9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807`
for UNSIGNED BIGINT `0  to 18446744073709551615`

- [Integer Types (Exact Value) - INTEGER, INT, SMALLINT, TINYINT, MEDIUMINT, BIGINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on used datatypes in your database and 32/64bit versions of your server, an integer has a specific limit.

A workaround might be to use strings in PHP and BIGINT in SQL.

http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.integer.php